does an insignia of claws stack with wraps of unarmed prowess?

Insignia of Claws: While wearing the insignia you gain a +1 bonus to the attack rolls and the damage rolls you make with unarmed strikes and natural weapons. Such attacks are considered to be magical.


Wraps of Unarmed Prowess: While you're wearing these cloth wraps, your unarmed strikes are considered magical for the purpose of overcoming immunity and resistance to nonmagical attacks and damage, and you gain a +1 bonus to the attack and damage rolls of your unarmed strikes.

Do these bonuses stack?

I’ve closed this as a duplicate, the linked question asks the same thing, but about a different magic item that does the same thing as the wraps.
